# Error when running any docker command by Jenkins on pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am running jenkins and docker on Ubuntu server 18.04.2 LTS and when starting 
jenkins pipeline to run docker commands, I have this error:

Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported.

See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.

script returned exit code 1

Can anyone help me ? Thank you

Comment: I tried to change JENKINS_HOME in the home directory and still not working.

Comment: Same happens to me even when running it from inside ansible-playbook. 
(on Jenkins shell)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by just adding "sudo" in front of the docker command